# Установка zip на windows

Tags: python

Здравствуйте обучаю python , столкнулся с проблемой которую не получается решить есть код:

после вылетает ошибка zip-qr не является внутренней или внешней командой

```
import os
import time 
source = ['"C:\\My Documents"', 'C:\\Code']
target_dir = 'E:\\Backup'
target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime ('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'
zip_command = "zip-qr {0} {1}" .format(target, ' '.join(source))
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
   print('Резервная копия успешно создана в', target)
else:
   print('Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ')
```

помогите решить проблему.

Comment: приведите ошибку в текстовом виде и удалите скриншот из вопроса. и еще. чему вы обучаете python?

Comment: Вставьте пробел между `zip` и `-qr`